# 3D similarity transformation in Meshlab or other

Tags: transform, similarity, point-clouds, meshlab, ply-file-format

I have two .ply datasets in Meshlab. A is a point cloud of a scene. B is a point cloud which contains 30% of the scene from A, but rotated, translated and scaled (7 deg of freedom) by unknown factors.

I want to get A and B aligned roughly by hand, just to get an idea of how well they match up at the overlapping part. Does anyone have some expertise on this? I would really like to use Meshlab but it seems there's no way of scaling/translating/rotating separate layers according to separate co-ordinate frames... There does seem to be a way of translating/rotating by manually selecting correspondences between the two layers, but this doesn't deal with the scaling issue (as far as i can see...)

I would ideally like to scale & align B as close as possible to A by hand, save down the .ply file of the transformed B, and then I can run some kind of iterative closest point on the new dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Mesh Layer->Matrix: Set translation/rotation/scaling.